# Convert an image type to file type flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, I have written a code to capture an image from the camera as a file then convert it to an Image to apply filters and crop it . After applying filters I want to again convert the image to file to upload to API. How can I convert it?

My code for image processing:

```
String imageFilePath;

 Future loadImage() async {
    final imageBytes = File(imageFilePath).readAsBytesSync();
    final newImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);
    var cropSize = min(newImage.width, newImage.height);
    int offsetX = (newImage.width - min(newImage.width, newImage.height)) ~/ 2;
    int offsetY = (newImage.height - min(newImage.width, newImage.height)) ~/ 2;

    img.Image destImage = img.copyCrop(newImage, offsetX, offsetY, cropSize, cropSize);
    if (widget.flip) {
      destImage = img.flipHorizontal(destImage);
    }
    FilterUtils.clearCache();
    setState(() {
      this.image = destImage;
    });
  }
```

Comment: create a new file and do writeAsBytes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```dart
Future<File> writeImageWidgetToFile(Image img, String path) async {
  final imgByteData = await img.toByteData();
  final buffer = imgByteData.buffer;
  return File(path).writeAsBytes(
      buffer.asUint8List(imgByteData.offsetInBytes, imgByteData.lengthInBytes));
}
```